# How can I batch convert image files and PDFs to TIFF?

Tags: macos, graphics, file-conversion

I have a lot `.jpeg`, `.png` and `.pdf` Files and I want to convert all of them to `.tiff` all at once.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `sips`:

```
for i in *; do sips -s format tiff $i --out $i.tif; done
```

Bash.

Comment: I love that sips ships with darwin / OSX!

Comment: As far as I know, *Image Events* is only an (AppleScript-enabled) application wrapper to the SIPS command line utility.

Comment: It should be `for i in *; do sips -s format tiff $i --out $i.tif; done`. Otherwise you'll get `Error: Unsupported output format tif`

Comment: Here's another option on how to solve the multi-page PDF limitation: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/365583/249129

Answer (score 12):

## Automator

You can batch convert these files by:

1. Open **Automator** from `/Applications`
2. Create a new **Workflow**
3. Drag the **Get Specified Finder Items** to the workflow builder.
4. Drag the **Change Type of Images** to the workflow builder. This will prompt you to add the Copy Finder Items action as a backup option. That's up to you.
5. Click the **Add...** button in the Get Specified Items action and select all your picture files.
6. Select the desired image type in the Change Type of Images.
7. Click the **Run** button.
8. Enjoy your batch converted photos!

In the end, your Automator window should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I would make one slight change—primarily a matter of preference. I would create this workflow as an application and eliminate the *Get Specified Finder Items* step. This would convert any image file, including single page PDF, or folder of image files, dragged onto the application icon into TIFFs. (Or, more properly said, make TIFF copies of all those files and place the copies on the Desktop.) This eliminates the need to pre-define the files to be converted and allows you to reuse the workflow for future conversions.

Comment: Yeah, that works too.

Comment: Is it possible to set this up so you can run it from Finder without having to set it up every time? Like, right click file > Convert to PNG, or whatever?

Answer (score 5):

However, the Automator solution by @Matt Love will not convert multipage PDF files to individual TIFFs. You would need to run two separate Automator workflows, one to convert PDF files to images and one to change the format of image files. As an alternative, you might consider [using AppleScript with Mac OS X's built-in Image Events](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/08.html).

Unlike a simple Automator workflow, the script given below (syntax-colorized version [here](https://gist.github.com/1951198)) converts images *and* PDF files to TIFF, [does error reporting](https://img.skitch.com/20120301-gdi48bnfjegexr7ccsk11tte1q.png) and does not break down when failing to handle some files. Before running the script, select the files to be processed in Finder.

EDIT: For multi-page PDFs, only page 1 is converted.

```
# this script converts all PDFs and images selected in Finder
# to the TIFF format and appends .tif to the file name

set t to (time of (current date))
tell application "Finder" to set sel to selection
set errors to {}
tell application "Image Events"
    repeat with img_file in sel
        try
            set img_file to img_file as text
            set img to open img_file
            save img as TIFF in (img_file & ".tif")
            if (class of result) is not file then error "could not convert to TIFF"
            close img
        on error errMsg
            set errors to errors & ((name of (info for (img_file as alias)) & ": " & errMsg & "\n") as text)
            try
                close img
            end try
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

# error report
set errcount to length of errors
set msg to (((length of sel) - errcount) as text) & " files converted to TIFF in " & ¬
    (((time of (current date)) - t) as text) & " seconds.\n\n"
if errors is not {} then
    set msg to msg & errcount & " errors occurred: \n" & errors as text
end if
display dialog msg
```

Comment: The *Change Type of Images* Automator action, at least the version provided with OS X 10.7, **will** convert single page PDF documents to a TIFF file. I've edited the answer to say you can't use it on multi-page documents. I haven't decrypted the Applescript to determine how it works with multi-page documents.

Comment: In Snow Leopard, the *Change Type of Images* Automator action does not process single-page PDFs either. The AppleScript converts PDFs to TIFF, but only the first page in multipage PDFs (thank you for pointing this out).

Comment: I just checked on a Snow Leopard system and the *Change Type of Images* module **does** convert single page PDF files—at least according to the documentation. I will test the function later.

Answer (score 3):

Next to an Automator script or a commercial tool to solve for multi-page PDFs, another option is to use [ImageMagick's convert tool](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). For example executing the following from the same directory:

```
for i in *; do magick convert -density 300 ./$i -depth 8 ./$i.tiff; done
```

Comment: Have to install Homebrew and do `brew install imagemagick` first if you haven't already

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, you can also cd into the directory of your image, and use:

```
sips -s format tiff input.pdf --out output.tiff
```

Source: http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/07/convert-images-using-terminal.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could construct such a custom workflow using the commercial program [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/150/batch-conversion-with-additional-functions.html) (US $40). You would use it a stand-alone program, but it also has certain functions that can be used in Automator workflows.

Here is some information from [GraphicConverter's page explaining their batch processing image editing functions](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/150/batch-conversion-with-additional-functions.html).

> **Batch conversion with additional functions**
>
> GraphicConverter offers you sophisticated batch  processing which
>   fully automates repetitive tasks applied to a selection of pictures:
>
> - Convert all the selected source pictures easily and quickly into a new format - regardless of whether there are 5 or 5,000 picture files;
>     you just define the type of conversion and set the details
> - During the conversion process you can apply up to 60 additional batch functions such as rotation, resize, change the resolution, etc.
> - Automate the removal of the Mac OS Ressourcefork before documents are uploaded if there are compatibility problems when the picture
>     files are placed in the internet
> - Create catalogs in HTML format for publication in the internet and adjust the colors, sizes, etc. to your individual requirements (see
>     examples)
> - Rename a selection of documents according to special criteria  quickly and easily
> - Join pictures together (e.g. for QuickTime VR)
> - Insert or extract IPTC information into or out of a variety of  document formats
> - and much more ...

[image]